# how can use microfrontends in nextjs

Tags: next.js, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm currently developing a university intranet that encompasses multiple departments. Each department offers unique services. To efficiently manage this complexity, I've opted to implement microfrontends.

The approach involves having one host frontend responsible for global components and authentication. Additionally, there will be separate microfrontends for each department, encapsulating their respective independent web applications. These microfrontends will be integrated into the host frontend, leveraging its components.

My question is: how can I effectively implement this architecture?

Thank you.

I've conducted some research and found that module federation could be a suitable solution for this architecture. However, I've encountered difficulties as it's not fully supported by the Next.js app router.